# Bootstrap: Select Tag Cutting off texts below

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular7

I have a weird style issue where selected option text inside select tag is hidden half by itself. I am using bootstrap 4 and "luxbootstrap.min.css" style. Below is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">My Racks</h1>>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="rack" [(ngModel)]="rack">
      <option [value]="rack" *ngFor="let rack of racks">{{rack}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Look like this luxbootstrap theme has extra padding in the form-control.

[image]

[image]

Solution: i add following snippet in style.css

```
select.form-control {
    padding: 0;
}
```

all help appreciated...

Comment: please add a snippet or can you share is there any margin occupying space using inspect element in the browser.

Comment: try increasing height of select element.

Comment: Yes, snippet would be helpful to replicate the issue select works fine with just bootstrap : https://jsfiddle.net/7nwstrva/5/

Comment: @AnshulRiyal you are correct. it look like form-control has extra padding in css

Comment: @phonemyatt Glad to help. Happy coding :)

Comment: Bootstrap adds static height to select box by default. So in order for text to display properly and centered vertically, control height should ideally be equal to top padding + bottom padding + 2*font-size. Or you can just remove the static height.

Comment: @ParaBolt, nice info. its better styling dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with select box padding

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment